# I am using Sequelize ORM and getting the following error when I am running my src/index.js file

Tags: node.js, orm, model, sequelize.js

[Screenshot of my error in GitBash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gquJ.png)

**Below is my models/index.js file.**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const process = require('process');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
      file !== basename &&
      file.slice(-3) === '.js' &&
      file.indexOf('.test.js') === -1
    );
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**Below is my models/airplane.js file.
**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Airplane extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
   Airplane.init({
      modelNumber: {
      types: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    capacity: {
      types: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
  }
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Airplane',
  });
  return Airplane;
};
```

**Below is my code in src/migrations folder**

```
'use strict';
/** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Airplanes', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      modelNumber: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      capacity: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Airplanes');
  }
};
```

**My folder structure looks like:**

src/models/airplane.js

src/models/index.js

src/migrations

**Below is the errror message in GitBash:**
C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\BACKEND_GRAPHY\Project\Flights\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:726
throw new Error(`Unrecognized datatype for attribute "${this.name}.${name}"`);
^

Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute "Airplane.modelNumber"
at C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\BACKEND_GRAPHY\Project\Flights\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:726:15
at C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\BACKEND_GRAPHY\Project\Flights\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:13469:38
at C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\BACKEND_GRAPHY\Project\Flights\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4967:15
at baseForOwn (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\BACKEND_GRAPHY\Project\Flights\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:3032:24)
at Function.mapValues (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\BACKEND_GRAPHY\Project\Flights\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:13468:7)
at Airplane.init (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\BACKEND_GRAPHY\Project\Flights\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:723:28)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\BACKEND_GRAPHY\Project\Flights\src\models\airplane.js:16:13)
at C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\BACKEND_GRAPHY\Project\Flights\src\models\index.js:30:54
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\BACKEND_GRAPHY\Project\Flights\src\models\index.js:29:4)

Node.js v18.15.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I tried changing the Airplane.init() funtion in the models/airplane.js by removing the modelNumber property and I tried the same thing with the capacity property in the function but the error won't resolve.

Comment: Check `DataTypes` that is passed to model initialization function